# How can I get all texts between two characters but with a chosen number?

Tags: c#, string

So simply what I want:

Input: Hey "There" "Random"

And I would simply:

```
GetTextBetweenBrackets(string userinput, 2);
```

Then

output: Random

```
static string GetTextBetweenBrackets(string text, int number)
{
    string Output = "";
    string[] split = text.Split(' '); 
    Output = split[number].Split('"', '"')[1];
    return Output;
}
```

That code works good but if the input is:

input: Hey "There random" "Love Cats"

```
GetTextBetweenBrackets(string userinput, 2);
```

output: Nothing

Comment: Don't split on space: `Output = text.Split('"', '"')[number - 1];` seems to work for me. edit: I don't think that split overload is doing what you expect, it's equivalent to `Output = text.Split('"')[number - 1];`.

Comment: What you implemented differs from what you tell. You tell: "get text between two characters". You implemented: "split a text at spaces". If you would implement what you tell, it could work.

Comment: Why are you passing double quote to `Split` twice.  It only needs to be in there once?

Comment: Is “get all texts between two characters” really, truly the problem you are trying to solve? I ask because there are no brackets in your text, “all text” between the second quotes is “Love Cats”, not “Love” as you said. Also this question is the [canonical example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) of an XY problem; that is, a question where you ask about your attempted solution without mentioning the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Well i need a way to know the first Text between two quotes from the second Text between two quotes

Comment: Sorry wrong title xD

Comment: In that case the output will be "There random" while i wanted "Love Cats"  as the output @Quantic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for you (but you should take care of potential exceptions)

```
static string GetTextBetweenBrackets(string text, int number)
{
    return text.Split('"').Skip(2*number-1).First();
}
```

Then

```
var result0 = GetTextBetweenBrackets("Hey \"There\" \"Random\"", 2);           //Random
var result1 = GetTextBetweenBrackets("Hey \"There random\" \"Love Cats\"", 2); //Love Cats
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of regular expressions to find a quote, get the text until the next quote which produces a match, then one can get the right match by indexing into it that result list.

```
static string GetTextBetweenBrackets(string text, int number)
{

     return Regex.Matches(text, @"\x22([^\x22]+)\x22") // \x22 is the hex escape for "
                 .OfType<Match>()
                 .Select(mt => mt.Value)
                 .ToList()
                 [number - 1];
}
```

`GetTextBetweenBrackets("Hey \"There random\" \"Love Cats\"", 2)` returns "Love Cats"

---

A reason to use this is that if there are other texts between your quotes, this will still work. Ex `GetTextBetweenBrackets("My \"Name\" is, well \"Earl\"", 2)` will return "Earl" and work, while the other solutions will fail due to just focusing on the one type of sentence.